# Java Web Server suddenly stops responding without any exception

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web-applications, webserver

I have a browser game built on a java web server using jsp.

I added a new module that uses some http session object and keep data in it. However, after it runs 3-4 hours, it suddenly stops working and freezes. When I check the error log, I dont see any exception thrown.

The server has 50-60 online in a moment.

I monitored the server using visualVM and here is the result after 4 hours until it stops :

[image]

I set the max memory as 1024Mb. As you can see its problem is not about the memory.

The thing that I notice is when the server stops, the thread amount increased.

According to the screenshot, should I doubt the httpsession object ? Why does the server stop responding ??

Comment: check "Deadlock detection" at jconsole.

Comment: in the moment it stops responding ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a system limitation or a deadlock.

Your thread graph looks like problematic : the number of living thread is important and  never decreases. A web application should be stateless. The living tread count should rises when the requests arrive but also drops when the requests are finished.
I have not the impression it is the case in your application.

MGorgon is right.

> You should also check "Deadlock detection" in jconsole.

If you use a JDK 6+ version, you could use [ThreadMXBean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html). It has a `findDeadlockedThreads()` methods and other interesting methods to address your need.

Anyway, if it is not a deadlock, to get more information about the cause of the problem, I advise you to look in the system log whatever you OS is. You would have maybe interesting things.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. But I couldn't get the "Deadlock detection" part. Should I check it when the system is running or it should be used right in time the problem occurs ? Because when I try it in normal running time, it says "No deadlock detected".

Comment: You are welcome. Interesting subject :)

You have the button in jconsole (in the Threads tab), not in jvisualvm. They are two different executables in the same `bin` directory of your jdk.

Comment: Oh I think I cant explain :) I already use JConsole and the "Detect Deadlock" button in Threads tab :) My question is when should I apply this ? When my site stops responding or any time when it is up ?

Comment: Sorry, I am confused. I deleted my previous comment. I though that the process of your server was terminated when your server froze. I read bad. I will go to sleep I think :)
So, if your process is always running, you must use  the "Detect Deadlock" option when the server seems to be stopped. If it is stopped because of deadlock, you should have some detected deadlocks.